# Hibernate - fetch only the latest versions of elements in contained collection

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have an entity :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("News")
public class News extends TVProduction {
private int audience;
private Collection<Reportage> reportages;

public News() {
    super();
    setAudience(0);
}

@Column(name = "audience")
public int getAudience() {
    return audience;
}

public void setAudience(int audience) {
    this.audience = audience;
}

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "Reportages_News",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "news_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "reportage_id")
)
public Collection<Reportage> getReportages() {
    return reportages;
}

public void setReportages(Collection<Reportage> reportages) {
    this.reportages = reportages;
}
```

}

And Reportage class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Reportage")
public class Reportage {
private Long id;
private String subject;
private int version;
private String content;
private Reporter reporter;

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "reporter_fk")
public Reporter getReporter() {
    return reporter;
}

public void setReporter(Reporter reporter) {
    this.reporter = reporter;
}
```

}

What I want is to have only the highest versions of Reportages fetched while fetching News. I tried to annotate Reportage with:

```
@Loader(namedQuery = "fetchFinal")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "fetchFinal", query = "SELECT t.* FROM" +
        "(SELECT id, subject, max(version) maxVersion, content, reporter" +
        "FROM reportage GROUP BY id) x" +
        "JOIN reportage t ON x.id = t.id AND x.maxVersion = t.version AND t.id = ?"
)
```

but It doesn't work, saying:

> Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

Any idea how to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
select * from reportage t where t.version = (select max(t2.version) from reportage t2)
```

**UPDATE:**

Have not tried this myself:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "fetchFinal", query = "SELECT t.* FROM" +
        "(SELECT id, subject, max(version) maxVersion, content, reporter" +
        "FROM reportage GROUP BY id) x" +
        "JOIN reportage t ON x.id = t.id AND x.maxVersion = t.version AND t.id = ?",
        resultClass=Reportage.class)
```

= add Resultclass

**UPDATE2**

If that doesn't work this certainly will (since I've done this myself); using Criteria:

```
Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(Reportage.class);

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Reportage.class);
dc.setProjection(Projections.max("version"));

crit.add(Property.forName("version").eq(dc));
return crit.list();
```

Comment: Same error - that in fact was my first attempt but it doesn't work either

Comment: BTW: if id is the primary key (or at least unique) then _GROUP BY id_ is pointless

Comment: Ahh, the lack of resultClass was the culprit! And regarding to group by, I've always thought that functions like max, avg etc. work only with group by statement - turns out I was wrong :)